# RecyclerView not updating on Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a recyclerview inside my fragment. I want to load data into it when i on my fragment's onCreateView();

Here's my code:

```
   @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_meter_reading, container, false);

    meterReadingsRV = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.meter_reading_recycler_view);
    adapter = new MeterReadingAdapter(getActivity(),this.readingsList);
    meterReadingsRV.setAdapter(adapter);
    meterReadingsRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    loadData();
    return v;
}
```

This is my loadData method()

```
  private void loadData(){
    readingsList = new Select().from(Reading.class).execute();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Im using ActiveAndroid to load data into database.

My problem is when i call notifyDataSetChanged the view never gets updated.

Why is that so? Thanks!

Comment: Can you check if readingsList is populated by logging. Also instead of initializing try adding  using add method

Comment: yup i already logged the readingList and it contains my data.

Comment: then try adding data to your list using addall method

Comment: hmmm...ok ill get back to you.

Comment: and set layout manager first and then set adapter to recyclerview. so reverse those statements

Comment: is this line of code running in background thread?
readingsList = new Select().from(Reading.class).execute();

Comment: @GaganSingh how exactly i can do that?

Comment: Share code of your Select class

Comment: its an ORM code. I Used Active Android for it. I already added Asynctask nothing happens

Comment: I already solved it. I just loop on the return of Select().from(Reading.class).execute(); and manually add each item on my readingsList. Dont know why equating it directly doesnt work.

Comment: @JCFrane you need to update the list that you use in the adapter. SO what you need to do is add elements to the same readingList instead of initializing it. Adapter is a bridge between you reyclerview and data. So you need to update the underlying data used in adapter and then refresh adapter